# Is using @NonNull in Retrofit's onResponse method good for Null Safety?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In my code there is a method to get some data from the API.

methods can return null. Is using `@NonNull Call<InitGet> call` is good solution in this case? Or should I do a simple null check using if-else to not get a null pointer exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@NonNull`

Doesn't change your code, it's a marker to say to the client of the method `"this code is not expected to return null"`

Therefore if you can still return null you should not use that annotation.

But you are on the right track - not wanting to return null, so that is a good thing.

Like you said, You can change your method to something like this which is "null safe":

```
@NonNull
public String getFoo() {
    String foo = something.getFoo();
    if(foo == null) {
       return "Foo was null, but this is a nice msg for the UI."; // or similar
    } else {
       return foo;
    }
}
```

In your case "aes key" sounds like something that you either have it or you don't - and if you don't then it's pretty bad. I would do this:

```
@NonNull
public String getAesKey() {
    String key = response.body().getAsKy();
    if(key == null) {
       throw new IllegalStateException(new NullPointerException("Key was null, but we need a key or everything is broken! Fail fast."));
    } else {
       return key;
    }
}
```